# Find the number of subgroups of order $25$ when $G=\Bbb{Z}_{360}\times\Bbb{Z}_{120}\times\Bbb{Z}_{75}\times\Bbb{Z}_{3}$

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, abelian-groups, totient-function

Let $G \cong \mathbb{Z}_{360} \times \mathbb{Z}_{120} \times \mathbb{Z}_{75} \times \mathbb{Z}_{3}$.

I want to find the number of subgroups $H \le G$ of order $25$.

First I found out that there are $124$ elements of order $5$ and $500$ elements of order $25$ in $G$.

I want to divide the subgroups to ones that are isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}_{5} \times \mathbb{Z}_{5}$ and those that are isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}_{25}$.

I start with $\mathbb{Z}_{25}$, so any subgroup of $G$ that is isomorphic ti it is generated by an element of order $25$. Now here is where I am not sure what to do. I saw someone calculate the amount by doing $\frac{500}{\varphi(25)}$ but I can't understand how did he get to it.

The same goes about groups of order $5$.

Help would be appreciated

Comment: Well, for each element of order 25, consider its powers from $0\to24$. The powers that are coprime with $25$ are those that also are elements of order 25. Hence, for each element of order 25, we can generate a group, but $\psi(25)$ elements all generate the same group.

Comment: I am not sure I understand why $\varphi(25)$ elements generate the same group. Could you maybe explain a little bit more?

Comment: $\psi(25)$ counts the number of numbers coprime to $25$ less than it. Combine that with my first comment, and it should make sense.

Comment: So you mean that if I take $g \in G$ of order $25$, then in $<g>$ there will be $\varphi(25)$ elements of order $25$, and since all those elements are of order $25$, then they all generate $<g>$. That's why we divide in $\varphi(25)$?

Comment: Yup, that's right.

Comment: Now all is clear, thanks